# Is there any way to interact with a canvas through a desktop application?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, desktop-application

I've been attempting to develop a Chrome extension that auto draws in skribbl.io for fun, and I'm really stuck on implementing dithering. It's just too slow. I've been trying to work out how to execute it in parallel, but to be honest, Javascript is just not my thing. I'm really uncomfortable with promises etc. It works by getting the canvas skribbl.io uses and sending input directly to it.

e.g

```
         draw: function (coords) {
            let startMouseCoords = getMouseCoords(coords[0]);
            canvasElement.dispatchEvent(createMouseEvent("mousedown", startMouseCoords));

            for (let i = 1; i < coords.length; i++) {
                let mouseCoords = getMouseCoords(coords[i]);
                canvasElement.dispatchEvent(createMouseEvent("mousemove", mouseCoords));
            }

            let endMouseCoords = getMouseCoords(coords[coords.length - 1]);
            canvasElement.dispatchEvent(createMouseEvent("mouseup", endMouseCoords));
        },
```

I was wondering if there would be any way to do this in a desktop application, as I feel much more comfortable in C++ or C# and I would likely have much better luck getting an algorithm of this sort to run at a decent speed. Is there any good way to do something like that through a desktop app? Perhaps even a Linux based browser that would let me interact with the web pages much more directly, instead of going through the Chrome extension system.

Comment: Puppeteer, Selenium, etc.

Comment: If you want to implement dithering, the "best" approach is probably to implement it as a WebGL shader and run that in a separate `<canvas>` (in a WebGL context) using data copied from the source 2D canvas . Also, why the heck are you emulating mouse movement instead of using the Canvas API directly?